# ASP .net 6 download file by httpclient - problem with stream

Tags: asp.net, .net, blazor

I'm creating blazor server app. I use external file storage with RestAPI.
I want to create download button to get file from storage. This may seem easy, but not necessarily.

From file storage I download HttpContent like that

```
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, _url);
        request.Headers.Add("auth-token", token);
        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _Http.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var content = response.Content;
```

next I act like this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-downloads?view=aspnetcore-6.0

```
        var fileStream = content.ReadAsStream();
        using (var streamRef = new DotNetStreamReference(fileStream))
        {
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFileFromStream", "file.txt", streamRef);
        }
```

For small files everything work great. But if I try to download large file (100mb), algoritm firstable download file to memory(RAM) of server and later save on local disk of client.

In ideal world I dream that when I click button download, file from external storage will download after delay (with progressbar) like physical file (no stream buffer) form http server e.g. https://www.example.com/file.txt. Of course by my BlazorServer Application with authorization and authentication, and whole neccesery services.

Comment: "For small files everything work great. But if I try to download large file (100mb), algoritm firstable download file to memory and later save on local disk."   Can you clarify the "algoritm firstable download file to memory and later save on local disk" part?  I'm afraid that is utter nonsense when it comes to  my reading ability.

Comment: First this file from storage service is stream to RAM my server, after stream complete file is able to download by user (begin download process). I need sth similar to multipart upload file, of course to download. User(Client) should get file like "directly" from my file storage service but by my blazor server app.

Comment: You don't need all this code then. `_Http` connects to your server so there's no need for extra tokens and headers. A simple `var stream=await _Http.GetStreamAsync(url);` should be enough. You don't need even that though if you only need to retrieve data from a URL without processing. You can create an `<a>` link with the `download` attribute. That's what the Javascript code you use does. Instead of writing any code, create an `<a href="@_url" download='file.txt' />` link.

Comment: Storage file server require bearer token and auth data. Those data are common for whole app, otherwise user has been authorised to download this file.

Comment: *moreover (instead otherwise) I add, I don't want to show my client my internal url (security)

Comment: As for the idea @PanagiotisKanavos, maybe use proxy? But I don't know how you should authorise with your file storage (API) in this case.

Comment: @mwrochna is this a different server from your own web server? In that case create a controller action that retrieves the file as a stream and returns that stream to your UI. You can still use `<a download>`. For large files you'll have to store the file to disk first instead of storing it in a 100MB buffer.

Comment: You'd need JS only if you need to talk to the third server from the *browser*. In that case it would be simpler to do everything in Javascript: use `fetch` to retrieve the blob, construct the `a` element in memory with a blob URL and call click on it.

Answer (score 2):

I have solution.

1. Create Service to service File Storage API
2. Create controller to avoid cros-origin error
3. Use microsoft tutorial to create download button https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-downloads?view=aspnetcore-6.0